# Modal View from multiple view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to display a view modally. The view itself works just fine but I cannot get it to pop up in this situation only:

- TabBarController
- - NavigationController
- - - TableViewController: I am trying to present it from this view, programatically, from the viewDidLoad method.
- - otherViews...

This is how the standard code is (taken from apple, please correct me if wrong):

```
LoginView *loginView = [[LoginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *loginNavigationController = 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];
[self presentModalViewController:loginNavigationController animated:YES];

[loginNavigationController release];
[loginView release];
```

However I cannot get it to work. Even with

```
self.parentViewController presentM...
self.navigationController  presentM...
self.tabbarController  presentM...
```

Or multiple together...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing and see if it works. But as per your problem is concern try to debug your application and see if there is any object is nil or not. And in case you have tabbarController+NavigationController then you need to present from tabbarController or try getting topViewController from current navigationController and then present the view modally.
Let me know if it works or not. If still it doesn't work send me your code by mail if you can I'll look into the issue.

**Edit**

One query - Do you want to push further viewController from the one you are trying to present modally?

Comment: Yes I do want to push further viewController from that one (it is the login view, and there is a "register" button there for newcommers that pushes a register view...).

Comment: @jeff does your problem solved? if not send me the code I'll look into the issue.

Comment: I tried the solutions you advised me to try but no luck. I created a new project specificaly designed to answer my problem with only a few classes. If I send you my code, you want me to zip you my xcodeproject file? thank you very much

Comment: Thanks alot, for other's info: problem was solved by Rahul, I needed to put the code in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: @Jeff Please accept the answer. Also up vote if my answer helped.